# How to go back into a while-loop, from an if statement?

Tags: java, while-loop, user-input

Here's what i've been working on. I'm trying loop this `while` method, using booleans. (My teacher is incompetent, so i've been learning out of textbook.)

```
else {  System.out.println("Do you want to restart? Y/N"); 
            string answer = scn.next();
            return;
            if (scn.hasNext() && !no)) {
                System.out.println("end");

            } else{   
                continue;
                }

                /*if (repeat) {
                continue;
                } else {
                System.out.println("End");
                break;
                }*/

            }
```

This is nested in a while loop like so ....

```
import java.util.Scanner; import java.lang.String;

public class booleanvariables {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int score1, score2;

    String answer, e;

    boolean bothHigh, atLeastOneHigh, atLeastOneModerate, noLow, tooLow, repeat;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter the first test score:\t");
        score1 = scn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second test score:\t");
        score2 = scn.nextInt();
        answer = null;
        e = "n";
        bothHigh            = (score1 >= 90 && score2 >= 90);
        atLeastOneHigh      = (score1 >= 90 || score2 >= 90);
        atLeastOneModerate  = (score1 >= 70 || score2 >= 70);
        noLow               = !(score1 < 50 || score2 <  50);
        tooLow              = (score1 <= 50 || score2 <= 50);
        repeat              = (answer == "yes" || answer == "y"); //|| answer == Y || answer ==     Yes);
        if (tooLow)
            System.out.println("Inputs are too low");

        if (bothHigh)
            System.out.println("Qualified to be a manager");

        if (atLeastOneHigh)
            System.out.println("Qualified to be a supervisor");

        if (atLeastOneModerate && noLow)
            System.out.println("Qualified to be a clerk");
            /** NESTED WRONG I'M AWARE
             */
        else {  System.out.println("Do you want to restart? Y/N"); 
            string answer = scn.next();
            return;
            if (scn.hasNext() && !no)) {
                System.out.println("end");

            } else{   
                continue;
                }

                /*if (repeat) {
                continue;
                } else {
                System.out.println("End");
                break;
                }*/

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: each time when i see `while(true)` i have goose bumps

Comment: Not sure to understant the issue here. My guess is, whatever goes wrong, it might be because of the `return;`  after the `System.out.println("Do you want to restart? Y/N")`. This will cause the program to exit without checking the choice of the user.

Comment: I tried formatting the code, but it's not even syntactically valid :(

Comment: Sorry, your question is quite unclear. Can you elaborate?
Maybe you can work with labeled breaks as decribed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: You should add a question.

Comment: I posted the whole code i have as a reference. I'm very aware of syntax errors; the syntax errors are there because i was experimenting with different approaches to do what i wanted done, and never removed them completley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much simpler than you think.

Just do it like this:

```
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop) {
    //do whatever you want here

    System.out.println("Do you want to quit?(yes or no");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("no")) {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

That way, if you enter "no", it'll set the boolean to `true`, which then will make the condition for the while loop, `!stop`, equal to `false`.

Comment: would a `do {`  `} while` work to test if it's true after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
answer == "yes"
```

You are checking if two objects are the same. You should use the equals method `answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("y")`

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and Working to My Liking**
I've reworked some branching. ( I use BlueJ as a compiler and it thinks this is an error without the `input = scn.nextLine();`

```
do {
//same booleans i've been using
if (!stop) {
            System.out.print("Do you want to quit? (yes or no):\t");
            //String input;
            input = scn.nextLine();
        }
        //String input;
        input = scn.next();


        if(input.equals("yes")) {
            stop = true;
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            return;

        }
    } while (!stop);
```

I really don't know why blue J doesn't like it when initialize input from within the `if` statement